# Is it necessary to clearTimeout inside a recursively invoked timer?

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, coffeescript

Is it necessary to call `clearTimeout()` inside a recursively invoked function in Coffeescript?

My concern is whether not calling `clearTimeout()` will possibly cause some sort of memory leak over time if this function is run many many times per second. My thinking is the JS garbage collector handles this, but want to double check.

A contrived example from a websockets/socket.io implementation I'm working on:

```
socket.on 'dataReceived', => @_recursive_fn()

_recursive_fn: ->
  @timer = setTimeout (=>
    clearTimeout(@timer) # is this necessary?
    @_recursive_fn() if some_condition == true
  ), 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `setTimeout` schedules a one-off event. Once the event has occurred, `clearTimeout` with that handle is a no-op.

Comment: With `setInterval` is this still true, since this recurses automatically?

Comment: @professormeowingtons: `setInterval` is different. It schedules a recurring event, and so it keeps recurring until you call `clearInterval`. (I should note that technically, neither of these is recursive in the traditional sense.)